# QWidget::layout() can't return QGridLayout?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qgridlayout

I have a QWidget that contains a QGridLayout, which in turn contains a handful of QPushButtons.  These are all generated programmatically.  Later in the code (separate from where the layout is defined), I need to be able to add more pushbuttons to specific row/column positions in the layout.

I tried using: `widget->layout()->addWidget(button, row, col)` to reference the layout and add the buttons.  However, `widget->layout()` only returns a generic QLayout item, which does not allow me to specify row and column values.  Is there any way to reference a QGridLayout from a specific widget, without having to know the layout by name?  I'm using Qt 4.8 if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always cast it to `QGridLayout*` by [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast):

```
auto gridLayout = dynamic_cast<QGridLayout*>(widget->layout());
```

If you're sure `widget->layout()` points to your `QGridLayout` you don't have to check and can use `static_cast`. Otherwise, check `gridLayout` against `nullptr`.